# Can we stop people from down voting answers that might not be bad?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

I asked a question at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035880/how-to-create-an-app-that-has-public-data, but immediately after I asked the question, someone down voted it.  My suggestion is, don't make the question or answer down voted just by one vote.

Comment: Hm... That's an extremely vague question, and it shows no prior effort. Why shouldn't it be downvoted? You don't even bother to tell us the language(s) you are working with...

Comment: How about you take the votes to heart, try to figure out what's wrong, and adjust the question? Gain upvotes once you're done, and we have a win-win situation. As for the question you linked, it's absolutely unclear and I wouldn't even have a clue where to start answering it.

Comment: Well check it yourself!

Comment: Perhaps read through this @user2273191 http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx If you do, and take the advice to heart, your questions will dramatically improve.

Comment: Your title talks about downvoting answers but you link a question in the body...

Comment: How about 10? Are 10 downvotes enough? Questions are voted down because they are not useful (Here on meta though, they are voted down because **someone doesn't agree with you**), your question is incredibly broad, shows 0 research effort, has no attempted solutions. Yeah, I'm sorry to tell you, it was downvoted rightfully.

Comment: Can we stop people from posting incoherent questions?

Answer (score 11):

You are right: people should not downvote good questions. But that is not what is happening here.

Askers should show that some effort was put into research before they are asked. Askers should also provide full details to explain the problem, including code to reproduce the problem. Askers should avoid including meta information ("*Okay. The title may not be that helpful, but I will clear it up here*") because it distracts from the question.

Your question has problems in all of those areas. However, it can be improved: Show the code that you wrote when you attempted to solve the problem. Consider including a screenshot if the code and description are insufficient.

Above all, recognize that Stack Overflow can help with specific problems, but is not a place to ask others to write your code or development plan for you.

Answer (score 7):

> […] don't make the question or answer down voted just by one vote.

Why should `1 != 1`?

One vote is just that: one vote. One person downvoteing shows up as one downvote. Two shows up as two. Seeing a question with one downvote is a signal that tells you that at least one person has evaluated it and found an issue. In the case of questions that is often roughly along the lines of the downvote hover text:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

This seems to fit your question reasonably well. It is entirely unclear what you are asking about and doesn't show any research effort. It is likewise not useful to anybody else because it doesn't even identify what platform or language you are working with.

The system seems to be working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that one upvote offsets 2.5 downvotes for questions.  So, if you get a mix of upvotes and downvotes, chances are you come out ahead.

Having said that, different people have different criteria for what deserves a downvote.  It's a judgement call.

Comment: I don't care.  Anyway, I'm sure that the guy who down voted my question didn't even read the question, because like I said, he down voted the question immediately after I asked it.  Immediately!

Comment: Also, maybe my question is so bad that it could get flagged, but, if there is a good question that gets down voted immediately after the question right after it was asked, you will be to blame!

Comment: @user2273191 It's not that big of a question. It takes seconds to read and only leaves one confused. Instead of complaining about the votes, make it a better question. That should be the way forward. Edit it, clarify the situation based on the comments you've received and then it might be reopened. I'll gladly vote for that if you make it a good question.

Comment: @user2273191 Somebody watching the new question feed can have the question in front of them in less than one second from the time you post. To an experienced eye, two or three seconds is more than enough to understand that the question doesn't have enough detail and isn't going to be answerable. Another second to vote and get back to you makes about 5 seconds from the time you post to the time a valid evaluation in the form of a vote can be on your screen. Trust us on this one: the problem is with the question, not the system. Your time would be better spent in learning how to fix it.

Comment: So fine then!  Tell me what to edit it to!  Ok?  Be fair!

Comment: As Jon Skeet commented, what is the coding problem you face, what have you tried so far, what platform are you using, etc. And follow the link I've put in my comment on your question here. If you address all the points raised there, you might have a decent question. Fair enough?

Comment: Another list of things to check (also by me): http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Well, I didn't start coding, so I don't have any problems.

Comment: Then unfortunately you don't seem to be having a question fit for Stack Overflow. (And it might explain why your question is so vague at the moment) Start coding, make some progress, and once you're stuck let us know.

Comment: You have a master-detail app but you haven't started coding??? That's a pretty neat trick!

Comment: Just an aside - for questions one up-vote only offsets 2.5 down-votes.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for clearing that up.  Edited my answer.